# NetBeans как среда разработки для flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, netbeans, ide

Пользуюсь NetBeans.
Очень интересно, есть ли, и если есть, то где достать и как установить плагин для NetBeans, который позволял бы программировать на Action Script 3 и компилировать .swf файлы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, официальной поддержки нет, но есть старый неофициальный проект плагина

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexbean/

По этому поводу был открыт тикет [157968](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=157968), но он, кажется, никуда не движется.